# Multi services - when to use mocks and stubs?

Tags: mocking, agile, stub

If say you're building a checkout and your remit is simply to render a confirmation page with usual details, including order number etc.

If you know that there is a service/API/endpoint that you will call,. but you have no idea about the contract nor WHO would even provide/werite/agree the contract, would this be a case where you would either:

a) mock what a reasonable endpoint might do, build and test against it (even though the final contract isn't at all up to you and thus could look completely different when it's actually done)
b) pause development and wait for the dependent contract to at least be proposed and documented (even if it's not committed) before starting any work in earnest

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially create an abstraction layer for the unknown api calls.

- Build your system using an abstraction for the api calls
- Make a reasonable guess about how you would expect the api calls to behave
- Initially plug in a mock implementation so that you can progress your work
- When the final contract is agreed and the real endpoint becomes available, swap out the mock for an implementation that works with the real code

This is similar to your option a), but the main difference is that you make it as easy as possible to swap in the real code when it arrives.

One advantage of this approach is that if you change the provider of this service in the future it would make it easier to swap in the new provider.

Disadvantages may include an increase in code complexity and a possible impact on performance.